# Как вернуть номер массива в переменную типа string?

Tags: c#

```
public static string GetNumber(params string[] number)
{
   number[0] = "Text1";
   number[1] = "Text2";
   number[2] = "Text3";
   return number.ToString();
}
```

Мне нужно как-то присвоить каждый текст по индексу в переменные по типу:

```
public static string Igrok = GetNumber[0];
public static string Status = GetNumber[1];
public static string Final = GetNumber[2];
```

Но мне пишет:

> Не удаётся применить индексирование через [] к выражению типа "группа
>   методов".

Мне нужно именно по номерам присваивать каждый текст.
Как правильно реализовать?
Просто стоит такая задача, через индекс подставлять текст, конечно можно и без этого обойтись сразу записать в переменную, но нужен именно такой подход)

Comment: Эм.. Ни одной нормальной строчки кода...

Comment: Тык Вы же применяете индексатор к методу. ```GetNumber[0]``` ясен пень не будет работать. Кстати, из описания сложно (если не невозможно) понять что-либо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static string GetNumber(params string[] number, int index)
{
   number[0] = "Text1";
   number[1] = "Text2";
   number[2] = "Text3";
   return number[index];
}
public static string Igrok = GetNumber(number,0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
public static string GetNumber()
{
   string[] number = new String() { "Text1", "Text2", "Text3" }
   return number;
}

public static string Igrok = GetNumber()[0];
public static string Status = GetNumber()[1];
public static string Final = GetNumber()[2];
```

, можно так:

```
public static string GetNumber(int i)
{
   string[] number = new String() { "Text1", "Text2", "Text3" }
   return number[i];
}

public static string Igrok = GetNumber(0);
public static string Status = GetNumber(1);
public static string Final = GetNumber(2);
```

, а можно вот так вообще:

```
public static string Igrok = "Text1";
public static string Status = "Text2";
public static string Final = "Text3";
```

Вот только все эти куски кода какие-то странные. Просто не могу понять Ваш вопрос!